# How to @Inject an abstract BaseActivity and its subclasses using dagger.android?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, kotlin, dagger-2

I'm using the new `dagger.android` package from [Dagger 2](https://google.github.io/dagger/) to inject Android dependencies in my project.

- I need all my Activities to be a subclass of an abstract `BaseActivity`
- In my `BaseActivity` I have member variables to be injected. This way:

  ```
  abstract class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
      @Inject
      lateinit var prefs: MyPreferenceDataStore
      ...// more @Injected members
  }
  ```
- I do it because I want subclasses of `BaseActiviy` can have access to injected members of `BaseActivity`:

  ```
  class SubClassActivity : BaseActivity() {
      override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {                
          val x = prefs.getXXX //use prefs variable from parent class
      }
  }
  ```
- This is my ApplicationComponent:

  ```
  @Singleton @Component(modules = arrayOf(
                  ApplicationModule::class,
                  ActivityBindingModule::class,
                  AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class
              ))
  interface ApplicationComponent {
      @Component.Builder interface Builder {
          @BindsInstance
          fun application(application: Application): Builder
          fun build(): ApplicationComponent
      }
      fun inject(app: AndroidApplication)
  }
  ```
- The `ApplicationModule` class has simple `@Provides` annotated methods:

  ```
  @Module
  class ApplicationModule {
      @Singleton @Provides
      fun providesMyPreferenceDataStore(context: Context): MyPreferenceDataStore {
          return MyPreferenceDataStoreImpl(context)
      }
      // more @Provides annotated methods
  }
  ```

  I think the problem is in my `ActivityBindingModule`

  ```
  @Module
  abstract class ActivityBindingModule {

      @PerActivity
      @ContributesAndroidInjector(
          modules = arrayOf(BaseActivityModule::class
      ))
      abstract fun bindBaseActivity(): BaseActivity

      @PerActivity
      @ContributesAndroidInjector(
          modules = arrayOf(
              BaseActivityModule::class
      ))
      abstract fun bindSubClassActivity(): SubClassActivity
  }
  ```

This is what I have tried so far:

- Make the `bindSubClassActivity()` method not to depend of `BaseActivityModule::class`, didn't work.
- Move the `providesMyPreferenceDataStore` from `ApplicationModule` to the `BaseActivityModule`, so that the class is:

  ```
  @Module
  class BaseActivityModule {
      @PerActivity @Provides
      fun providesMyPreferenceDataStore(context: Context): MyPreferenceDataStore {
          return MyPreferenceDataStoreImpl(context)
      }
  }
  ```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
Error: [dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)] com.example.BaseActivity cannot
be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
This type supports members injection but cannot
be implicitly provided.
```

Comment: where BaseActivityModule code ?

Comment: Hi @AhmedAbd-Elmeged, see edit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I didn't understand exactly what you try to do but this solutions based in what i understand

AppComponent should look like this

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [
    AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
    AppModule::class,
    ActivityModule::class])
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<DaggerApplication> {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application): Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent
    }
}
```

your base activity which will inject all the objects

```
abstract class BaseActivity : DaggerAppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var prefs: SharedPreferences

    //other objects to inject

}
```

The activity that will inherit from it eg:MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : BaseActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        prefs.getBoolean("s", true)
    }

}
```

And Activity module

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityModule {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract fun bindMainActivity(): MainActivity

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract fun bindBaseActivity():BaseActivity

}
```

AppModule

```
@Module
class AppModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun providesMyPreferenceDataStore(application: Application): SharedPreferences {
        return application.getSharedPreferences("test", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    }

}
```

Comment: It worked. Now I have another issue, but it is part of a different question. Thanks!

Comment: OK no problem ask :D

Comment: I'd have to edit the entire question. Will post another and let you know here.

Comment: i think it's better to ask new question so if any one face the same problem can find a solution

Comment: So, We have to add all those activities / fragments in `ActivityModule` which are extending BaseActivity / BaseFragment, Am I right?@AhmedAbd-Elmeged @JorgeE.Hernández

Comment: Yes if you have the base Activity/Fragment extend dagger. when you extend your main activities/fragments you will need to add themin the `ActivityModule ` @MaulikDodia

Comment: What If you have too many activities & fragments in your project, `ActivityModule` class will become quite long. Isn't there any other solution for that?@AhmedAbd-Elmeged

Comment: In a big/production app you won't put them in one class you will modularize and scope them. for example, you have registration module that has all the login signup UIs, one for payment..etc depending on your use case. also if you have for example 5 user fragments are used in one activity you will put them in one module and scope them to the activity scope @MaulikDodia

Comment: @AhmedAbd-Elmeged That sounds great. Thanks a lot. Can you guide me to some good docs for this new Dagger 2 implementation?

Comment: You are welcome! check this blog https://medium.com/@iammert/new-android-injector-with-dagger-2-part-1-8baa60152abe it will help you a lot I think it's 3 parts read them and you will have a solid understanding to it.